# Node.js CouchDB and Nano 'error happened in your connection'

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I have been looking around for well over 2 hours now trying to find SOMETHING that would give me any kind of direction with this issue but simply cannot find it.

I am using Node.js and CouchDB with docker-compose. I am also using express and nano. I have stripped my server.js file down to nearly nothing and still keep getting this

**Error:**

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/nano/lib/nano.js:137
        reject(new Error('error happened in your connection'))
                ^
 
Error: error happened in your connection
    at responseHandler (/usr/src/app/node_modules/nano/lib/nano.js:137:16)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/nano/lib/nano.js:427:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
 
Node.js v17.0.1
```

I have tried about 10 different ways of laying out the `url` but just cannot get any kind of indication as to why it just will not work. I have tried using  `curl -X PUT admin:admin@127.0.0.1:5984/posts/"001" -d '{"name":"Conner"} '` and it gets inserted without and issue.

**server.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
var nano = require('nano')('http://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:5984');
var posts = nano.use('posts');

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const cors =require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
    extended: true 
}));
 
const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';


async function asyncCall() {
  const response = await posts.insert({_id: "001"}, 'rabbit')
  return response
}
asyncCall();

app.use('/', express.static('public'));
console.log('up and running');


app.listen(PORT,HOST);
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install express --save
RUN npm install nano --save
RUN npm install cors --save
RUN npm install -g loadtest --save

COPY server.js /usr/src/app/server.js
COPY /public /usr/src/app/public

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

 node1: 
  build: ./s1
  depends_on:
   - couchdb1
  container_name: s1a4
  ports:
   - "81:8080"

 couchdb1:
  image: couchdb:3.2.0
  container_name:  cdb1
  ports:
    - "5984:5984"
  environment:
    COUCHDB_USER: admin
    COUCHDB_PASSWORD: admin
```

Comment: Your working curl uses port 5984 while your code uses port 5986, that can't be good...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson My bad, I was just testing something with that. That did not change a thing, the error persisted when I had it at 5986 and 5984..

Comment: The hostname should also probably not be 127.0.0.1 (localhost) to talk to another container, so maybe http://admin:admin@couchdb1:5984 would work better. (or maybe cdb1 is the hostname you should use, haven't had coffee yet)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Oh my god you king. That works. Thank you so much. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since CouchDB is running in its own container and not on localhost, your connection string needs to point to the other container instead of 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Since you called the CouchDB service "couchdb1", the connection string should instead be;

```
admin:admin@couchdb1:5984
```